# Weighted Least Square

Tags: plotting, fitting

I need to fit data to a line.
This data also includes tolerances.

**Now, I was wondering, if there exists a method, to account for those tolerances?**

For instance, a data point with a lot of tolerances should not be given the same weight as a data point with small tolerances.

Here is a sample of my data:

x| Data-point (y) | +/- tolerance

1| 120.984      | 0.426248

2| 132.194  | 0.418291

3| 130.413  | 1.260100

4| 127.687  | 0.414457

5| 125.710  | 0.410716

6| 128.188  | 1.431200

I was thinking of applying weighted least squares, but I don't know how to implement it.

```
data = {{1, 120.984}, {2, 132.194}, {3, 130.413}, {4, 127.687}, {5, 
    125.710}, {6, 128.188}};
tol = {0.426248, 0.418291, 1.260100, 0.414457, 0.410716, 1.431200};
LinearModelFit[data, x, x, Weights -> 1/tol]
```

I don't know... what do you think of the method ? Is the weight correctly chosen ?

Comment: `NonlinearModelFit` has a `Weights` option. Perhaps you could start there.

Comment: Is this a question about the *Mathematica* computer language?  If not, it belongs on Cross Validated stack exchange (statistics).

Comment: @DavidG.Stork thanks for the advice.

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks for the hint! You can see my first try in the question.

Comment: "what is the appropriate weight" really is a statistics question.  My guess is since your tolerances are fairly similar what you have done is pretty good, but no doubt there is a formally correct approach.

Comment: See:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34325/regression-modelling-with-unequal-variance

Comment: what are your tolerances by the way?  No way you will fit a line, close to those tolerances (or maybe its toy data ?)

Comment: Related to @george2079 's comment:  Your tolerances (if standard deviations or 95% confidence half-widths) seem small compared to the lack of a linear fit of the 6 sample points given.  A plot of your data with error bars much like what george2079 shows in his answer is essential for determining if you need to account for the weights or not.

Comment: @JimBaldwin Okay, thanks a lot for your comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a non-statistician approach:

Example data:

```
data={{0, 9.90427}, {1, 8.63647}, {2, 8.38828}, {3, 12.1254}, {4,7.83307}, {5, 9.91714}, {6, 16.2134}, {7, 22.6182}, {8,26.1951}, {9, 28.5855}, {10, 30.2941}}
tol={3.04485, 6.88185, 8.32968, 6.69215, 8.60092, 9.38202, 2.39801,1.0914, 2.9695, 1.14305, 0.634177}
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
ErrorListPlot[MapThread[{#1, ErrorBar[#2]} &, {data, tol}]]
```

[image]

simulate additional data based on the variance at each point, and fit to that:

```
sim = Flatten[
   MapThread[ 
    Function[{a}, {#1[[1]], a}] /@ 
      RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[#1[[2]], #2 ], 200] & , {data, 
     tol}], 1];
fit = LinearModelFit[sim, x, x]
```

> 4.41422 +2.42061 x

the OP's approach for comparison:

```
fit2 = LinearModelFit[data, x, x, Weights -> 1/tol]
```

> 5.32159 + 2.46208 x

```
Show[{ListPlot[sim, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[.25], Gray}], 
  ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red], Plot[{fit[x],fit2[x]},{x, 0, data[[-1,1]]}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: @corey979 sorry, `xd=data[[All,1]]`  (no need for that though, fixed)